# Query a Windows DHCP server : find MAC from hostname

Tags: command-line-interface, dhcp, windows, mac-address

From my computer, I want to query my DHCP server to find a specific mac adress.
I want to enter the hostname to search, and getting back the Mac address.

Something like :

```
netsh dhcp server scope show clients |find hostname
```

This command line doesn't works, but maybe you have some tips ?

Thank you,

Comment: If you remove the `|find hostname`, what error messages do you receive?  I can see two issues: 1.) You're not specifying the dhcp server name/IP, `netsh dhcp server \\servername`...  2.) You're not specifying which scope you want: `netsh dhcp server \\servername scope 10.130.40.0 show clients`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable with Powershell, this script will help you find what you need:
https://sites.google.com/site/assafmiron/ServerScripts/get-dhcpleases

This script almost works as well.  It currently lists extra clients. Some regex magic with the find command parameters could fix this. Save to to a .cmd file and specify your dhcppserver and a valid scope.

```
for /f "skip=4 delims=: tokens=2" %%a in ('nslookup %1') do set IP=%%a
netsh dhcp server \\ourdhcpsvr scope 192.168.1.0 show clients|findstr "%IP%"
```

Output should look like this

`172.16.19.78     - 255.255.248.0  - c6-33-5f-cb-a7-a5   -4/25/2017 8:26:07 AM   -D`

Comment: The question is "find MAC from hostname" but your script does NOT show MAC. And the linked script gives a screenful of errors as soon as you load it into PS.

Comment: I confirmed that the script does indeed display the MAC address. I added the output to my answer. Most scripts (like the one I linked) require some tweaking for your environment. Did you try? Why do you feel the need to trash a 5 year old answer when the OP confirmed it met he/her needs?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running it on? Because the script just hung when I ran it. Tried both Win 10 and Server 2016. The netsh bit on its own doesn't show MAC address for me. I don't want other people to waste time like I did on something that doesn't work. Perhaps it did on an old version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 10 works.  Did you run it as admin?

Answer (score 0):

With `netsh dhcp server \\servername scope 10.130.40.0 show clients` you get a list without client names, when you add "1" at the end of this line, you get the client names as well:

```
netsh dhcp server \\servername scope 10.130.40.0 show clients 1
```

Comment: The question is "find MAC from hostname" but this does NOT show MAC.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

The following three PowerShell cmdlets (and some specific parameters which will be listed later) can combine to obtain just the Mac address of a device that has a Dhcp lease:

- [`Get-DhcpServerv4Lease`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/get-dhcpserverv4lease)
- [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)
- [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)

### Description

Rather self-explanatorily, `Get-DhcpServerv4Lease` will display information relating to all the leases contained in the specified scope, including the Mac address of our target device. This is a good start, but there is a lot of unwanted information being displayed. Let's address that with some filtration.

Perhaps less self-explanatorily, `Where-Object` allows us to add a filtration criterion (or multiple filtration criteria) to our query. We will filter on the `HostName` property of the objects returned by `Get-DhcpServerv4Lease` so that only information pertaining to our target computer is displayed. We've now filtered out most of the unwanted information, but there is still some left. Let's filter some more.

Definitely less self-explanatorily, `Select-Object` can perform even more filtration. We will filter on the `ClientId` property (which in this case is equivalent to the Mac address), thus discarding any information that is not the Mac address.

### Show me the code!

When we put it all together with the help of the pipeline (note the "|" pipe character separating the cmdlets), it looks like this:

```
PS 7.2> $DhcpServerHostname     = "dhcpserver01"
PS 7.2> $DhcpScopeIpAddress     = "10.0.0.0"
PS 7.2> $TargetAbsoluteHostname = "pc01.example.domain"

PS 7.2> Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName $DhcpServerHostname -ScopeId $DhcpScopeIpAddress | Where-Object -Property "HostName" -Like -Value $TargetAbsoluteHostname | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "ClientId"

01-23-45-67-89-AB
```

### Notes

1. Yes, unfortunately, the Ip address of the Dhcp scope **is** required.
   For some reason, the team behind this cmdlet decided they wouldn't
   allow searching across all scopes. Very frustrating, as it seems
   such a glaring omission. If you need help finding the Ip address for
   your target scope/s, ask another question.
2. The hostname I've used in the example is an absolute hostname. I
   would say it is more common for Dhcp entries to use the absolute
   name than not, hence the inclusion, but the relative hostname (i.e.
   `pc01` in this case) may work instead. Alternatively, one could
   employ the use of a wildcard (i.e. an "*" asterisk in PowerShell), but
   an explanation of that might require a separate question be asked
   due to the added complexity it entails.